# Recording https session with JMeter

Tags: session, jmeter

I am having problems recording a session which requires acccess to an external https site (Payment Express/DPS).

While recording the session I get presented with:

There is a problem with this website's security certificate. 
 .
 .
Security certificate problems may indicate an attempt to fool you or intercept any data you send to the server.
  We recommend that you close this webpage and do not continue to this website.
  Click here to close this webpage.
  Continue to this website (not recommended).

When I click continue to the website I get a page expiry error.

Comment: What happens when you access the site using browser (without recording)? Does this site require you to authenticate?

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a similar problem recently.

I fixed it by unchecking "Attempt HTTPS Spoofing".

Check your HTTP Proxy Server and if it is checked, clear it.

Comment: It was an interesting problem this one. I was using IE to record the session and it was causing the page to expire. When I used firefox instead, it only presented a warning once for the untrusted certificate and it was plain sailing from there.

Answer (score 1):

Https recording is successfully working in new version of Jmeter 2.9 as of today. I had to import proxy certificate and play around with Firefox to get this working. Previous to this version Jmeter has https spoofing for which it requires to be checked. With new versions that option is gone away and it may work straight away. Else you need to import the certificate as per below post

Refer this link for more information [Https recording using Jmeter](http://qtp-automate.blogspot.co.uk/2013/05/https-recording-with-new-jmeter_22.html)

Answer (score 1):

Check out BlazeMeter's JMeter Chrome extension:
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/blazemeter-the-load-testi/mbopgmdnpcbohhpnfglgohlbhfongabi?hl=en

You still have to signup to BlazeMeter (JMeter as a service) but you can sign up to a free (for life) plan and still use the extension to record and everything you do in your browser into a JMeter script.